# Query String Parser Logic

Tags: url, query-string

Required to Parse the query string from URL. It is observed that for a sample query String, python and Apache STring Tokenizer is giving different Outputs [order of parsed string is varying]example:

For query string q=uri+path+parser&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

python gives : 
{'q': ['uri path parser'], 'sourceid': ['chrome'], 'sugexp': ['chrome,mod=6'], 'ie': ['UTF-8']}

where Apache active String Tokenizer gives :

Key [q]   Value : [uri+path+parser]

Key [sugexp]   Value : [chrome,mod]

Key [sourceid]   Value : [chrome]

Key [ie]   Value : [UTF-8]

The order of the parsed result are different. Want to know the resaon why parse_qs is giving different order and what is the standard query path string parsing logic/algorithm?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi Yes, Apache Missed "=6". The string tokenizer for APache can be modified  for such errors. What I want is how important the order of parsing is and what is the standard parser logic for such query string.